# Launching black screen appear : Mac OS app

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen

I want to launch my mac app in full screen and hide the `menu` and `doc` so the user can not switch the app or can see another app. so I used the below code to launch windows in full screen.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
      super.viewDidAppear()
            let presOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.hideDock, .fullScreen]

            let optionsDictionary = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions :
                                        NSNumber(value: presOptions.rawValue)]

            self.view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.main!, withOptions:optionsDictionary)
            self.view.wantsLayer = true

  }
```

but it shows a black screen when the app is launch see the image.[image]

So my question is what's the best way to open the mac os app in full screen with hiding `Doc` and `Menu`